# Qt3D draw a shpere or circles that is a light source

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, 3d, qt3d

I use Qt3D with C++ and I would like to draw a circle that is also a light source but I also want the light to have a specific range, for example 10 as the unit. How can I do that? Please describe in as much detail as possible how to calculate the range for the light and apply it on the circle. I am new with Qt3D.

Thank you in advance!!!

like this:

[image]